# How to get a background from a video?

Tags: c#, video, background, video-streaming, emgucv

I need to get a background image from a video. I am thinking about running the video for about a minute or so to get it's background. Upon playing the video, the program will check what pixels changed every frame, then from that I think I can build a background from the video.

[Here is the screenshot of the video]

[image: http://postimg.org/image/vxzt8smxh/]

And I edited it manually to get something like [this]

[image: http://postimg.org/image/88adk3ok5/]

Is there any way on how can I get the background automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it easily on code, but if you only want to do it once,

I guess you can take some of the "cleaner" background images and work with them, you can use the guide "*[Video: How To Easily Remove Unwanted People From a Scene Using Photoshop?](http://petapixel.com/2015/08/11/video-how-to-easily-remove-unwanted-people-from-a-scene-using-photoshop/)*"

Comment: Thanks! But I need to do it automatically cause soon I will use a live video feed